# Express.js and NodeJs, lose (+) on url query

Tags: node.js, express

I need to send a + operator in my uri query but it changes to blank space, i trie to use `encodeURIComponent` but it does not work,

this is a example of my uri:

`/calculate?formula=Formule:n=log(Q/C)/log(1+R),data: {Q:139179.87, C:115000, m: 6,i:1.75%}`

when i print my query param on my controller:

`Formule:n=log(Q/C)/log(1 R),data: {Q:139179.87, C:115000, m: 6,i:1.75%}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII Encoding Reference, the reference to "+" is:

> %2B

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

As Guilherme Martin, you need to encode it, now, the logic is:

- If you are sending the data as parameter, you can encode it using encodeURIComponent function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
- If you are encoding a complete uri (eg: url), you need to use encodeURI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI